# Move Image Left & Right When it Zoomed

Tags: java, android, zooming, pinchzoom

How to move image  right to left when it zoomed ? I have done zooming on images and now don't know which codes to write for creating movement using finger once it zoomed.

Please have a look at my code and give me your precious reply. Edit my code if possible. Thanks in advance.

MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.ZoomControls;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView img;
    ZoomControls zoom;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        zoom = (ZoomControls) findViewById(R.id.zoomControls1);

        zoom.setOnZoomInClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            int w = img.getWidth();
            int h = img.getHeight();

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = 
                new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(w + 10, h +10);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

            img.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    });

        zoom.setOnZoomOutClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            int w = img.getWidth();
            int h = img.getHeight();

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = 
                new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(w - 10, h -10);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

            img.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ZoomControls
    android:id="@+id/zoomControls1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp" />
```

Comment: Just to have a clearer picture...you want to achieve this on your own ? since I used very good libraries that handle this for you

Comment: I don't know how to exceed further with coding. Please help me I need it for my application ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this library..it easy to implement and works flawlessly

[Image Zoom Library](https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom)